letter and bigram composition for each word in the dataframe
I have a data frame with words and I want to extract the letter and bigram composition for each word.
Data:
df$text

[1] "table"
[2] "run"
[3] "mug"`

And in the end I want to receive the output:

 1      a b c d e..z aa ab bb...zz 
table   1 1 0 0 0..0  0 1  0    0

First, I was trying to extract all the letters using Quanteda:
text <- c("table", "run", "mug")

dict <- dictionary(list(a= "a",
                        b = "b",
                        c = "c",
                        d = "d", 
                        e = "e",
                        f = "f",
                        g = "g", 
                        h = "h",
                        i = "i",
                        j = "j",
                        k = "k",
                        l ="l",
                        m = "m",
                        n = "n",
                        o = "o",
                        p = "p",
                        q = "q",
                        r = "r", 
                        s = "s",
                        t = "t",
                        u = "u",
                        v = "v", 
                        w = "w",
                        x = "x",
                        y = "y",
                        z = "z"))


corp<- corpus(text)

tokens(corp) |>
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = dict) |>
  dfm()

But it did not work out:
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 26 features (100.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
       features
docs    a b c d e f g h i j
  text1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  text2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  text3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[ reached max_nfeat ... 16 more features ]

I am totally new in this, and if you have any hint how to do that, please, help. Thank you!

You can simplify your dictionary with: dictionary(setNames(as.list(letters), letters))

For the single letters, you can use the following code:
toks <- tokens(corp, "character")
print(dfm(tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary=dict)), max_nfeat=26)


Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 26 features (85.90% sparse) and 0 docvars.
       features
docs    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  text1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  text2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  text3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

You should be able to obtain the two-letter combinations in a similar way as long as you set up the dictionary.
twos <- apply(expand.grid(letters, letters), 1, paste, collapse = "")
dict2 <- dictionary(setNames(as.list(twos), twos)) 
print(dfm(tokens_lookup(tokens_ngrams(toks, n=2, concat=""), dictionary=dict2)), max_nfeat=30)


Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 676 features (99.61% sparse) and 0 docvars.
       features
docs    aa ba ca da ea fa ga ha ia ja ka la ma na oa pa qa ra sa ta ua va wa xa ya za ab bb cb db
  text1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  text2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  text3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[ reached max_nfeat ... 646 more features ]

